# When is the Lagrange multiplier 0?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Hi there I am reviewing for a final on convex optimization and encountered a problem that I am not sure about.

Consider a convex optimization problem:
$$\min f_0(x)$$
$$\text{subject to }f_i(x)\le0, i=1,...,m, Ax=b,$$
that satisfies Slater's constraint qualification.

Suppose $x^*$ is optimal, with $f_1(x^*)=-0.2$. Is true then that for every dual optimal point $(\lambda^*,\nu^*)$, we have $\lambda_1^*=0$?

This question is from the Stanford open course: 
http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/quizzes/duality.html

I don't understand why it is true. Is it because we have $f_1(x^*)=-0.2$ instead of $f_1(x^*)\le-0.2$? How do we know the constraint does not constrain the minimum?

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrange multipliers associated to inequalities of the form $f_i(x) \leq 0$ satisfy
*complementary slackness*:

$$
\lambda_i f_i(x^{\star}) = 0, \; \forall i = 1, \dots, m,
$$

and in your case you have $f_i(x^{\star}) = -0.2 \neq 0$. Therefore, the only way for
the product $\lambda_i f_i(x^{\star})$ to be equal to $0$ is when $\lambda_i = 0$. If you knew that $f_i(x^{\star}) = 0$, only then *could* $\lambda_i$ be nonzero - but it would depend on the rest of the KKT conditions.